# Django Many to Many migration can't insert null into id

Tags: django, oracle, django-migrations

I'm trying to migrate a column from a Char field to a Many-to-Many field running Django 1.8.2. I'm doing a custom Data Migration, to move the data properly. When I try to migrate, I get a database error, can't insert null into the many to many table id column.

My models, simplified:

```
class LicenseArea(models.Model):
    #appraisal_account = models.CharField(max_length=17, null=True, db_index=True)
    appraisal_account = models.ManyToManyField(TaxAccount, db_table='LicAreaTaxAccount', related_name='accounts_for_license_area', related_query_name='license_area_for_account', null=True)

class TaxAccount(models.Model):
    account = models.CharField(max_length=17, db_index=True)
```

So I first create TaxAccount objects in a RunPython block, then remove the old field and add the new one, like so:

```
    migrations.RunPython(create_tax_account_objects),
    migrations.RemoveField(
        model_name='licensearea',
        name='appraisal_account',
    ),
    migrations.AddField(
        model_name='licensearea',
        name='appraisal_account',
        field=models.ManyToManyField(related_query_name='license_area_for_account', related_name='accounts_for_license_area', db_table='licenses_LicAreaTaxAccount', to='licenses.TaxAccount'),
    ),
```

All that works. My issue comes when I try to migrate the data, relating the LicenseArea object with its corresponding TaxAccount object. In another RunPython block, I try the code shown below (I've tried in both directions; acct.licensearea_set.add indicates that the TaxAccount model has no licensearea_set attribute, while the second option shown below gives me the IntegrityError (ORA-01400) that I can't insert null into the ID column :

```
for la in LicenseArea.objects.all():
    acct = TaxAccount.objects.get(account=la.appraisal_account_temp)
    #acct.licensearea_set.add(la)
    #la.appraisal_account.add(acct)
```

How do I solve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `null=True` is not necessary in s M2M relationship.

Comment: Yes, thanks, the migration mentions that as well. I had removed it from the migration, but didn't remember to update models.py. I've done so now :-).